# rel attribute returns same value always

Tags: php, codeigniter, get, hidden, rel

I have code which retrieves value from db and displays it using foreach loop. When I click on return product it will open a popup window. Problem is I have passed a variable as rel attribute but it gives only last row value from the loop. I need to get the product_stock value correspond to the product I clicked to return. What happens here? Why it is wrong?

```
<?php
if(!empty($product_details))
{                           
    foreach($product_details->result() as $data)
    {
?>  
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td><?php echo $data->product_sku; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data->product_name; ?></td>
            <td class="text_right"><?php echo $data->product_stock; ?></td>
            <td class="text_right" ><?php echo $data->product_price; ?></td>
            <td class="text_right"><?php echo $data->product_total; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a id="edit_user" data-toggle="modal" base_url="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" rel="<?php echo $data->product_id; ?>" style="padding-left:7px;" href="#userformedit"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
                <a onClick = "return confirm('Are you sure want to delete')" style="padding-left:10px;" href="<?php echo site_url();?>products/delete/<?php echo base64_encode($data->product_id).'/'.base64_encode($data->purchase_id)?>"> <i class="icon-remove-circle"></i></a>
                <a id="return_product" rel="<?php echo $data->product_stock; ?>" style="padding-left:7px;" href="#userform2" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-sort-by-attributes-alt"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

And I have used that product_stock as hidden like below. But it shows always same value which is from last row.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_stock" id="return_stock" value="<?php echo $data->product_stock; ?>" />
```

And my function is in model like below

```
function RetriveProductDetailsEdit($pro_id) {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tb_product');
    $this->db->where('product_id', $pro_id);
    $resultrows = $this->db->get();
    return $resultrows->result();
    ;
}
```

And I have passed this in controller. Nothing wrong with this I think

Comment: show your $product_details query?

Comment: I have added to question

Comment: how  may rows return $product_details qry?

Comment: it depends on products. This time it is 3

Answer (score 1):

your query already return result so change your foreach like below:

```
foreach($product_details as $data)
    {
      ....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hidden should also be put in foreach loop and also name should be different for each row so replace name="return_stock" as name="return_stock_product_id; ?>". Here i used product id because it will be unique.